# Random walk with floor at $0$

Tags: random-walk

This weekend my SO and I were trying to analyze a problem which boiled down to a 1-dimensional random walk with a floor at 0.  That is, starting at 0, move $\{-1, +1\}$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each, but anything which would go to -1 instead remains at 0, without hindering a later move to 1.

What are the properties of this form of walk?  Specifically, after $n$ steps, what does the probability distribution look like?  Expected value?

We worked out (by hand) the results for $n=3$ thru  $n=6$, but ideally we'd like to see what it looks like when $n=52$.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating a few values by hand, it seems that the probability of being at $m$ after $n$ steps is
$$
  p_{n,m}=\frac1{2^n}\binom{n}{\lfloor(n-m)/2\rfloor}
$$
for $m\leq n$. Indeed we can verify this inductively using the recurrence
$$
  p_{n+1,m}=\begin{cases}
    (p_{n,m-1}+p_{n,m+1})/2&\text{if }m>0,\\
    (p_{n,m}+p_{n,m+1})/2&\text{if }m=0.
  \end{cases}
$$